# Using only 1 resource file instead of 1 resource file per form/other strings

Tags: c#, resources, localization

We are localizing our forms and strings in a project and are having a problem; Visual Studio creates a resource file for each form when setting Localizable to true.

It's nothing more than a minor nuisance having to send all of the resource files to translators, but is it possible to get VS to use a global resources file instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to add resource files (.resx) for each culture to the solution file and assign the language to the thread culture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others already said, it is possible to use global resource file *manually*. I believe that it is actually more problematic and less maintainable but still possible.

Now onto why MS decided on one resource file per form. Well, from Internationalization point of view, this solution is ***better***. On one hand it gives translators one important thing: the context. On the other hand, it is typical for project to grow. It is really unlikely that you will make changes to all forms at once. And you know what? Depending on your deal with translation vendor, you can usually spend less on Localization if just few percent of strings would change. That is just because they can use Translation Memory (TM) software.
With one global resource file, there is usually no context and no way to reasonably use TM. The result is, translations are less accurate and take longer (one needs to actually read large blocks of text to make sure everything is correctly translated).

By the way, you do not need to send out individual resource files. Instead you can use some kind of translation kit generator (or translation manager software) to create something useful for translators (for example translation memory friendly file). Sadly, I cannot give you the names of such tools (although I know that there are few of them) since my employer is using custom system for that and I didn't have a chance to work with other tools.

Answer (score 2):

Like Yoda would say, possible it is.

You will have to dynamically translate the dialogs when they are loaded. I did this on several projects and I would say it's much better than having localized resource files.

Comment: That sounds like a bigger nuisance than just shipping off multiple resource files, sadly. :(

Comment: Think in longer terms, when you will start to change the dialogs, add new languages. Who is going to keep all this stuff updated? You?

Answer (score 0):

WinFrom doesn't support generating a global resources for Forms automatically in VS.
You must assign the strings by yourself. For example:

1. Add a Resources.resx with Resources.designer.cs to your project;
2. Define your strings in Resources.resx.
3. In your form.cs code, assign the strings in constructor like:

   ```
   Label1.Text = Resources.Label1Text;
   ```